Configure Amplify in a Next.js App Router application
I have a Next.js project using Amplify and it works great on my Pages Router application, however, when I try migrating to the newer App Router I get some problems.
Pages Router Config
In this version of the code my pages/_app.tsx file looks like this:
import '@/styles/globals.css';
import '@/styles/fonts.css';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import TagManager from 'react-gtm-module';
import { AppProvider } from '@/src/contexts/AppContext';
import { AlertProvider } from '@/src/contexts/AlertContext';
import AlertBanner from '@/src/components/basics/AlertBanner';
import AccessManager from '@/src/components/auth/AccessManager';
import { configureAmplify, amplifyTheme } from '@/src/utils/amplify-config';
import { ThemeProvider, Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

configureAmplify();

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (process.env.GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID) {
      const tagManagerArgs = {
        gtmId: process.env.GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID,
      };

      TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <AlertProvider>
      <Authenticator.Provider>
        <ThemeProvider theme={amplifyTheme}>
          <AccessManager>
            <AppProvider>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </AppProvider>
          </AccessManager>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Authenticator.Provider>
      <AlertBanner />
    </AlertProvider>
  );
}

The Amplify config comes from the @/src/utils/amplify-config file:
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { I18n } from 'aws-amplify/utils';
import { translations, Theme } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

// Config docs found here: https://docs.amplify.aws/gen1/nextjs/tools/libraries/configure-categories/
export function configureAmplify() {
  const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL;

  // Define redirects based on environment
  const redirects = [
    `${baseUrl}/account`,
  ];

  if (baseUrl !== "https://app.example.com" && baseUrl !== "http://localhost:3000") {
    // Add localhost redirect for development
    redirects.push('http://localhost:3000/account');
  }

  Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
      Cognito: {
        userPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
        userPoolClientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
        identityPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
        loginWith: {
          email: true,
          oauth: {
            domain: process.env.COGNITO_DOMAIN,
            scopes: ['openid', 'email', 'phone', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
            redirectSignIn: redirects,
            redirectSignOut: redirects,
            responseType: 'code'
          }
        },
      }
    },
    API: {
      GraphQL: {
        endpoint: process.env.APPSYNC_ENDPOINT,
        region: process.env.AMAZON_WEB_SERVICES_REGION,
        apiKey: process.env.APPSYNC_API_KEY,
        defaultAuthMode: 'userPool',
      },
      REST: {
        myapi: {
          endpoint: process.env.API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT,
          region: process.env.AMAZON_WEB_SERVICES_REGION,
        }
      }
    }
  });

  I18n.putVocabularies(translations);
  I18n.setLanguage('es');
}

// Theme docs found here: https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/theming
export const amplifyTheme: Theme = {
  name: 'my-theme',
  tokens: {
    colors: {
      primary: {
        10: '#e6f0ff',
        20: '#cce0ff',
        40: '#99c2ff',
        60: '#66a3ff',
        80: '#3385ff',
        100: '#0067f1', // Your original primary color
      },
      font: {
        primary: '#333333',
        secondary: '#666666',
      },
      background: {
        primary: '#ffffff',
        secondary: '#f5f5f5',
      },
    },
    components: {
      button: {
        primary: {
          backgroundColor: '{colors.primary.100}',
          color: '#ffffff',
          _hover: {
            backgroundColor: '{colors.primary.80}',
          },
          _active: {
            backgroundColor: '{colors.primary.60}',
          },
          _focus: {
            backgroundColor: '{colors.primary.60}',
          },
        },
      },
      heading: {
        color: '{colors.font.primary}',
      },
      text: {
        color: '{colors.font.secondary}',
      },
      card: {
        backgroundColor: '{colors.background.primary}',
        borderColor: '{colors.primary.20}',
      },
    },
  },
};

This configuration works well as it is with the Pages Router.
App Router Config
When I tried migrating my project to the App Router I got into trouble with the Amplify configuration. This is my current app/layout.tsx file:
import '@/styles/globals.css';
import '@/styles/fonts.css';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import AmplifyClientConfigurator from '@/src/utils/amplifyClientConfig';
import Providers from '@/src/app/providers';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'pey',
  description: 'Más que un método de pago, ¡únete a la revolución!'
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="es">
      <body>
        <>
          <AmplifyClientConfigurator />
          <Providers>
            {children}
          </Providers>
        </>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

This file invokes the amplifyClientConfig file:
'use client';

import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { I18n } from 'aws-amplify/utils';
import { translations } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { getAmplifyConfig } from '@/src/config/amplify';

Amplify.configure(getAmplifyConfig(), {
  ssr: true
});

I18n.putVocabularies(translations);
I18n.setLanguage('es');

export default function AmplifyClientConfigurator() {
  return null;
}

Which also calls the config/amplify file which has this code:
import { type ResourcesConfig } from 'aws-amplify';

export function getAmplifyConfig(): ResourcesConfig {
  return {
    Auth: {
      Cognito: {
        userPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID!,
        userPoolClientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID!,
        identityPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID!,
        loginWith: {
          email: true,
          oauth: {
            domain: process.env.COGNITO_DOMAIN!,
            scopes: ['openid', 'email', 'phone', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
            redirectSignIn: [`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL!}/account`],
            redirectSignOut: [`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL!}/account`],
            responseType: 'code'
          }
        },
      }
    },
    API: {
      GraphQL: {
        endpoint: process.env.APPSYNC_ENDPOINT!,
        region: process.env.AMAZON_WEB_SERVICES_REGION!,
        apiKey: process.env.APPSYNC_API_KEY!,
        defaultAuthMode: 'userPool',
      },
      REST: {
        myapi: {
          endpoint: process.env.API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT!,
          region: process.env.AMAZON_WEB_SERVICES_REGION!,
        }
      }
    }
  };
}

As you can see I tried to simplify the config to make it work, but this has taken me no where. I followed this AWS docs but they didn't solve my issue. As I wait for a response, I will try changing the structure I return in the getAmplifyConfig() and see if something else works.

Thanks for taking the time to read and try to find a solution to this, I'm new to App Routes and this configs are making me crazy.

